# Multiple Unresolved Identifiers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image]
I have no clue how to fix these errors because I'm an amateur developer but they keep reoccurring over and over again no matter what I do. Is there a way I can get it to stop once and for all?

Comment: I would recommend posting code instead of a picture for code. Then add comments to where the errors are exactly. But anyway, your 2nd error is because you have too many ")" after hide keyboard

Comment: Either you added extra curly braces or missed few.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you may have an extra curly bracket since the unresolved identifier means that it doesn't know about the item specified at the location that it's written. I think you have an extra curly bracket after the "Declare hide keyboard tap" block of code. Proofread your code for small mistakes like that. Usually when many similar errors like this show up, it's caused by something small